# Goroutines with http.HandleFunc

Tags: go

I want to know if  code 1 manage internal goutines and can use all the cores of one CPU when the requets will increase(dozens) or if per each handler I have to put the key word go that indicate that the funcion handler will be manage by one gorotine like is show it in code 2, and so can use all the cores of the server.

code 1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func HandlerOne(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("message one")
}

func HandlerTwo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("message two")
}
func main() {

        http.HandleFunc("/R1", HandlerOne)
        http.HandleFunc("/R2", HandlerTwo)

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":9998", nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Server failed: ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

code 2

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
    )

    func HandlerOne(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("message one")
    }

    func HandlerTwo(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("message two")
    }
    func main() {

        go http.HandleFunc("/R1", HandlerOne)
        go http.HandleFunc("/R2", HandlerTwo)

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":9998", nil)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Server failed: ", err.Error())
        }
    }
```

Note: Both run without problems and you be able to test it with

```
curl -l http://localhost:9998/R1
```

or

```
curl -l http://localhost:9998/R2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2 is wrong. Package http handles all this stuff for you.
Just make sure you invoke your program with an appropriate GOMAXPROCS, e.g. like `GOMAXPROCS=4 ./main`